# JQuery Mobile JS script runs first time but not when returning to page

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a JQuery Mobile page set up as such:

```
<body>
        <div class="normal" data-role="page" data-title="Photo Stream">

            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/photostream.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
                // Wait for Cordova to load
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

                // Cordova is ready
                function onDeviceReady() {
                                }
                </script>

            <div id="programholder">

          ~~addtional HTML~~
```

The external JS script `photostream.js` works when the app first opens, but then wont work again if I return to this page. I am assuming this is due to how AJAX loads the pages on top of each other, but seeing as my external link was within the `data-role="page"` div I assumed this got triggered each time that element reappeared.

Is there a way to have the external JS file reload again whenever this page is re-visited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want your external js file - photostream.js to be explicitly loaded every time a particular page loads. But this doesnt happen in JQuery Mobile because of the way AJAX loads the pages.

Off the top of my head, have you tried binding the external script to be loaded when the [pageshow](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/) event is triggered.

```
 $("#page1").on('pageshow', function(event, ui){
      var filename = "photostream.js";      
      var fileref=document.createElement('script');
      fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
      fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
   });
```

Comment: Awesome! Yep that was my problem and this worked. I gave my `data-role="page"` an ID and wrapped my script with `$( "#photostreampage" ).on( "pageshow", function( event, ui ) {   });`